# Cannot drop large materialized view in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, materialized-views

I have a materialized view thats larger than 50gb.

When I want to go drop the materialized view, it keeps coming back with

> Size (58.45 GB) is greater than max_[table/partition]_size_to_drop (50.00 GB)
> 2. File '/var/lib/clickhouse/flags/force_drop_table' intended to force DROP doesn't exist
> How to fix this:

1. Either increase (or set to zero) max_[table/partition]_size_to_drop in server config
2. Either pass a bigger (or set to zero) max_[table/partition]_size_to_drop through query settings
3. Either create forcing file /var/lib/clickhouse/flags/force_drop_table and make sure that ClickHouse has write permission for it.
   Example:
   sudo touch '/var/lib/clickhouse/flags/force_drop_table' && sudo chmod 666 '/var/lib/clickhouse/flags/force_drop_table'. (TABLE_SIZE_EXCEEDS_MAX_DROP_SIZE_LIMIT) (version 24.1.5.6 (official build)). (TABLE_SIZE_EXCEEDS_MAX_DROP_SIZE_LIMIT)

I tried setting the max_table_size_to_drop to 0, but with no success

Comment: Follow the chapter 3 of the introduction you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command:

```
drop view ... SETTINGS max_table_size_to_drop = 0;
```

Comment: You could explain *why* this should be tried.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#max_table_size_to_drop

`max_table_size_to_drop` this is a global server settings, try to change it in
`/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/max_table_size_to_drop.xml`

```xml
<clickhouse><max_table_size_to_drop>0</max_table_size_to_drop></clickhouse>
```

after that restart `clickhouse-server`